# String.Concat inefficient code?

Tags: c#, string, .net-4.0, concatenation

I was investigating String.Concat : (Reflector)

[image]

very strange :

the have the values array ,

they creating a NEW ARRAY for which later they send him to `ConcatArray`.

Question :

Why they created a **new** array ? they had `values` from the first place...

### edit

code :

```
public static string Concat(params string[] values)
{
    if (values == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("values");
    }
    int totalLength = 0;
    string[] strArray = new string[values.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
    {
        string str = values[i];
        strArray[i] = (str == null) ? Empty : str;
        totalLength += strArray[i].Length;
        if (totalLength < 0)
        {
            throw new OutOfMemoryException();
        }
    }
    return ConcatArray(strArray, totalLength);
}
```

Comment: Probably because it makes ConcatArray more efficient, not having to special case for nulls.  You do know it isn't copying all of the strings right?  It's just creating a new array of references to the existing strings.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how `totalLength` could ever be less than zero.  What silly thing am I overlooking?

Comment: @LarsTech when overflowexception occures - the int is negative....

Comment: Wait, how were you inspecting `Concat`? I've been trying to figure out how to view the code inside built in methods, but all I've found is that I need to use cecil.

Comment: I'm wondering why it throws `OutOfMemoryException()` when `totalLength < 0`. It is misleading.

Comment: Too bad you didn't paste the code itself...

Comment: @Walkerneo: Take [ILSpy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx) or [dotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) to look into the assemblies. Another source would be [TypeDescriptor](http://typedescriptor.net/browse).

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Well for one thing, it means that the contents of the new array can be trusted to be non-null.... and unchanging.

Without that copying, another thread *could* modify the original array during the call to `ConcatArray`, which presumably could throw an exception or even trigger a security bug. With the copying, the input array can be changed at any time - each element will be read exactly once, so there can be no inconsistency. (The result may be a mixture of old and new elements, but you won't end up with memory corruption.)

Suppose `ConcatArray` is trusted to do bulk copying out of the strings in the array it's passed, without checking for buffer overflow. Then if you change the input array at just the right time, you could end up writing outside the allocated memory. Badness. With this defensive copy, the system can be sure<sup>1</sup> that the total length really is the total length.

---

<sup>1</sup> Well, unless reflection is used to change the contents of a string. But that can't be done without fairly high permissions - whereas changing the contents of an array is easy.

Comment: Another thread could modify the original during the copy too. This seems to me to not be correct reasoning. (I didn't downvote, just didn't upvote.)

Comment: @Jason: It doesn't matter though - each element is only read *once* (note the copy to `str` rather than repeated access) - so either it will be read *before* the change or *after* the change. (Some elements can be read before the change and some after, and that's fine.) The `totalLength` will definitely still be appropriate for the *new* array, and all the values will still be guaranteed to be non-null.

Comment: @JonSkeet ( im surly not the downvoter also ) but :  what if a thread change the content of `values` while it is being copied ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir: It doesn't matter: on an element-by-element basis, you'll either see the new value or the old value. You *won't* see one value, use that to work out `totalLength`, and then use a *different* value in `ConcatArray`.

Comment: Your conjecture is correct; this is to ensure safety if someone is modifying the array on another thread.

Comment: @Eric Lippert: I guess it depends on what you mean by "thread safe." There is a race condition, no?

Comment: @Jon Skeet: I get that, but there's still a race condition that is not being avoided by this.

Comment: @Jason: It's a race condition as to whether you get the new value or the old value - but that's not the point of the copy. The point is to stop a *malicious* caller from screwing up the security. You could see an old value or a new value, but you won't cause a buffer overflow or a `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: I get that. I just don't want people to walk away thinking "thread safe" means completely bullet proof against issues from multi-threading. There is a race condition, and that is a form of thread unsafe in my world. It's a critical race condition, in that the output is non-deterministic when there are multiple threads involved.

Comment: @Jason: You are right; I should have called out that the "safety" I am talking about is not "thread safety" -- whatever that is -- but rather *memory safety*. The string code is behind the scenes going to use unsafe code to fill in the new buffer, and we must at all costs avoid corrupting memory. If the result is nonsensical because someone mutated an array that was being used on another thread, that's their problem; at least there *is* a result and an uncorrupted heap.

Comment: @JonSkeet why do they check if the size of the array is less than a 0 ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir: They're checking `totalLength`, which is the size in characters - if that's less than 0, then it means we've overflowed the bounds of `int`. Admittedly it could have overflowed *and then gone positive* which seems a little big of a bug. (Might give that a try and see what happens...)

Comment: @JonSkeet But what if another thread _is_ modifying the array _right after_ entering the for loop? the copy hasn't been finished yet...

Comment: @RoyiNamir: It can't modify the *size* of the array. It doesn't matter whether it's modifying the elements. For each element, we'll *either* use the original element *or* we'll use the modified element, and we'll do so consistently for that element. It's only the consistency that's important.

Comment: @JonSkeet Do you mean that some other guy can do in another thread: `values = new string[10000...]` ? Also, how can this be :`if (totalLength < 0)` {how can the total size be negative , and if its becuase the overflow exception , it should be like : "index out of range...or something..."} ? ( or should I ask it as another question in SO...)

Comment: @RoyiNamir: If the other thread did that, it wouldn't affect the value of the `values` parameter at all. For the overflow exception, I think the point is that you've requested a huge string - and even if it were feasible to represent that, you couldn't allocate a single object requiring that much memory, so `OutOfMemoryException` is reasonable. At a guess :)

Comment: It seems I don't 100% understand and I need to Digg dipper. so I asked a new Question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14292125/string-concat-and-thread-safety

Answer (score 16):

> Why did they create a new array?

I can confirm Jon's conjecture; I have the original source code in front of me. The comments indicate that the reason for the copy is because some foolish person could be *mutating the array that was passed in on another thread*.  What could then happen?  The calculation of length could say that there will be a hundred bytes of string data in the result, but by the time the copy happens, there could be a million bytes of string data in the array.

That would be bad. The problem is prevented easily by making a copy.

Comment: The problem is mitigated, not prevented; the other thread could still mutate the source array before the copy is completed.

Comment: @phoog: Right; the problem that is prevented is *memory corruption*. The output string can still be completely unrelated to the input strings due to race conditions, but memory will not be corrupted.

Comment: Ah, I see, because the code reads the length of the string after it is written to the new array, so the totalLength variable is always consistent with the total length of the strings in the new array.

Comment: Perhaps this might be a good time to remind the readers that one does't need to be a C# compiler developer (or even a Microsoft employee) to actually see the original source for most framework assemblies, thanks to the [Microsoft Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/) program.

Answer (score 4):

They created a new array to normalize out `null` entries into `String.Empty`.  This couldn't be done on the provided `values` array because then they would be modifying the input.

Answer (score 2):

> Inefficient

No, it doesn't matter. That array creation and copy is blazing fast relative to the concatenation, it's only copying references.

It looks like they do it to convert `null` strings in the input array into `String.Empty` (they can't do this on `values` because it would be modifying the input which is a no no), and to detect concatentations that would overflow before actually doing the concatenation (that's what the `if(totalLength < 0)` test is for). Additionally, they can use `totalLength` to allocate the memory for the concatenated string up front, which is more efficient.

Comment: It doesn't matter in most cases, but if the array is huge, the memory overhead will not be insignificant, and the likelihood of large object heap fragmentation will be significantly higher.

Comment: @phoog: If the array is huge then you are almost certainly making an even huger string, and so you already have bigger problems to worry about than the array copy.

Answer (score 0):

Probably to make sure it doesn't change over the lifetime of the method. Which would lead to `totalLength` not fitting the content of the array anymore.

I suspect that `ConcatArray` uses some unsafe memory copying, and doesn't recheck the string `Length`s again. One could rewrite it to avoid the allocation, but one additional small, short-lived allocation is pretty cheap.

Answer (score 0):

as far as I can see they do some work with this - guess you don't want to mutate the original one ... remember you want your strings immutable same for the Concat-function of course - don't change a parameter-reference if not stated ....