# String.Concat and thread safety?

Tags: c#, .net, string, multithreading

*After a[sking this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9910486/string-concat-inefficient-code) , I still have a question.*

*I got both excellent answers but I'm still having a trouble finding **how** could this actually be occur:  ( how could a fault situation can occur) :*

I will start with an example :

```
public void Do(string [] g)
{
   g=null;     //<========
}

void Main()
{
    var t=new string[3];
    t[0]="1";   t[1]="1";   t[2]="1";
    Do( t);
    Console.WriteLine ( t.Length);
}
```

the notated line can be execute in a different thread but each thread has its **own** `g` variable !
 (and please remember that I *can't* add items to an arrray. cause array length is created at creation)

No matter what will I do with the *function* `Do` - (no matter in what thread) , the Console.Writeline result will always be `3` ( unless using `ref`).

so lets see the real code :

```
    public static string Concat(params string[] values)
  #1  {
  #2      if (values == null)
  #3       {
  #4            throw new ArgumentNullException("values");
  #5       }
  #6        int totalLength = 0;
  #7        string[] strArray = new string[values.Length];
  #8        for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
  #9          {
  #10            string str = values[i];
  #11            strArray[i] = (str == null) ? Empty : str;
  #12            totalLength += strArray[i].Length;
  #13            if (totalLength < 0)
  #14            {
  #15                throw new OutOfMemoryException();
  #16            }
  #17         }
  #18        return ConcatArray(strArray, totalLength);
  #19   }
```

My saying is : once I'm on #1 , in thread `X` , this thread will forever will have array with length 3.

If *another* thread wants to destroy/change the array length ( which I cant understand *how* , cause the array has fixed length , all he can do is making it `null`) - it will have a *different* copy of pointer address.

I must be missing something here.

- What am I missing ?
- what is the code which other thread could execute which will cause an error ?(assuming we don't copy the array).

Comment: @ilya lines number are necessary for my question and for answer reference. please don't remove them.

Comment: It's really silly downvoting question after 3 minutes, when the question requires at least 5 minutes to get the point.

Comment: The issue is not what if someone changes the value of local variable g. The issue is what if someone changes the value of `g[0]`? That doesn't change the length of array t, but it does change the *total length of all the strings* in array t.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> what is the code which other thread could execute which will cause an error ?

```
string[] data = { "1", "2", "3" };
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem( () => { data[0] = "one"; } );
string total = String.Concat(data);
```

Without the intermediate array there would be a race condition,  the Thread could change `data[0]` *after* its length was added to `totalLength` but *before* the (presumably unsafe) call to `ConcatArray()`. The low-level method would then copy 5 chars to a buffer of size 3.

Answer (score 6):

I went over Jon Skeet and Eric Lippert's answers in the original thread, and I believe you're misinterpreting their answers. They're worried that if you don't copy the strings to a new array, someone will come along and change `{"1","2","3"}` to `{"a very very", "long string", "(but much longer, yes?"}` between the time `ConcatString` first evaluates the input and performs the concatenation.

Note that line 12 doesn't deal with the length of the *input array*, but with the length of the *final output string*. All these checks deal with the results of concetenation, not the input array.

Comment: Exactly. The length of the array can't change, but the *elements* in the array can change, which affects the total length of the strings.

Answer (score 2):

Array references are passed into the method, so each thread (in this case) would have its own reference g. Each thread can change what its own reference points to (eg, g = null) however when you access items in g, eg g[0], both threads will access the same item.

So, the problem is `g[0] = null`, not `g = null`.

Comment: But if you look at the answers ( in the link) all of them said that the reason for copying is changing the **length** and not the content!!! of the array. and not the content

Comment: @RoyiNamir - Jon Skeet is talking about `totalLength` which is the length of the _result_, not of `values` or `strArray`. And it derives from the _content_ of `values`.

Comment: Arrays are not passed by reference. Array references are passed by value (as are all arguments by default). It's a subtle but important difference.

Answer (score 1):

The following lines ensures data consistency in case the array content is modified in other threads

```
  #11            strArray[i] = (str == null) ? Empty : str;
  #12            totalLength += strArray[i].Length;
  #18        return ConcatArray(strArray, totalLength);
```

Race is still there but before line no. 11, But if original array is used (in case of data corruption) wrong information may be passed to `ConcatArray` function.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9910626/859154  he is talking about the length and not the values of the arrays.

Comment: May be I am not clear, by data consistency, I was referring to totalLength Parameter in `ConcatArray` function call that will result in wrong output (and may be exception)

Answer (score 1):

What John Skeet and Eric Lippert meant was that the calcuation of the total string length can lead to different results if the array contents can change after the length has been calculated. Because the concat operation is done in unmanaged code buffer overuns can occur if the string length afterwards did change.

To illustrate the issue here is a repro of the issue they were talking about:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static string[] arr = new string[] { "1", "2", "3" };
        static string[] arr2 = new string[] { "1111", "2222222", "2222222222222222222222" };

        [MTAThread]
        public static void Main()
        {
            ThreadStart[] funcs = Enumerable.Range(0, Environment.ProcessorCount * 4).Select(i => new ThreadStart(MutateArray)).ToArray();
            foreach (var func in funcs)
                new Thread(func).Start();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static void MutateArray()
        {
            Random rand = new Random();
            while (true)
            {
                int i = rand.Next(arr.Length);
                // swap array contents with contents from another array so arr will always
                // contain a mixture of arr and arr2 without knowing at which point of time which contents
                // are inside it.
                lock (arr)
                {
                    string tmp = arr[i];
                    arr[i] = arr2[i];
                    arr2[i] = tmp;
                }

                Do(arr); 

            }
        }

        static void Do(string[] g)
        {
            AllocateBufferWithRightLength(g, StrLen(g));
        }

        static void AllocateBufferWithRightLength(string[] g, int strLen)
        {
            int newLen = StrLen(g);
            if (strLen != newLen)
            {
                throw new Exception("Invariant broken");
            }
        }

        static int StrLen(string[] g)
        {
            int strLen = 0;
            foreach (var str in g)
            {
                if (str != null)
                    strLen += str.Length;
            }
            Thread.Sleep(1);
            return strLen;
        }



    }
}
```